# Serenity + Rest services

Tags: java, rest, serenity-bdd

I am trying to demo serenity with Restassured at my workplace here and show them how awesome and easy it is to use in comparison to using jasmine.js
How ever I am stuck with few things in the basic test I am trying to do
My test says

```
Given we have valid credentials for the client using this test
  When we try to serach for a medicine '<medicine>' 
  Then we get a valid '<perfLabel>' response with search results
  |medicine|perflabel|
  |Salbutamol|perflabel1|
  |Panadol|perflabel2|
  |Salbutamol (GA)|perflabel3|
```

When I go into the next step

```
@When("we try to serach for a medicine '(.*)' ")
    public void tryToSearchUsingEquals(String medicine)
    {
    tsApiActions.requestServiceSearchWhichEquals(medicine);
    }


In my Step method



@Step
  public void requestServiceSearchWhichEquals(String medicine)
  {
  host = "http://www.int.abc.com.au/api/cs/v1/terminology-service/trade-product/search-summary?offset=0&limit=20&prefLabel=eq "+medicine+"&sort=prefLabel DESC&cache=false";

  requestSend(host); 
  }
```

The questions I have are

1. How do i inject the variables(Salbutamol, Panadol) into the uri?
2. How do I put this URI into a seperate properties file and call it in the Step method?

Any help is really appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RestAssured requests follow the same code structure which should be added into your sendRequest method:

```
given().
   param("prefLabel", medicine).
when().
   get(URL).
then().
   body(containsString(medicine));
```

URL can come from property file, but you need to create a method to upload it before test run and then you have to create a getPropety() method to get the current value you need.

I suggest to read the official documentation here:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured